# Remove underline from CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink

I see the other answers here on StackExchange, but I cannot seem to get the code right to remove the underlining from my hyperlinks!

In my Stylesheet here is everything relating to links:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

I added this line of text myself, trying to insert the code, here is what my theme already contained:

```
a {
  transition: color 0.18s ease, background-color 0.18s ease, border-color 0.18s ease;
  outline: none;
  color: #161616;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #b49543;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

Anyone see what is wrong? I am seeing all text decoration marked as 'none'....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There could be a rule with a higher specificity overriding your indended behaviour.

Comment: You also might want to try adding `text-decoration: none;` to `a:active` as well.

Comment: you can F12 in chrome to check the a css;

Answer (score 2):

You can see if there are other rules with a higher priority that are overriding your settings by using the developer console in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.

Alternately, you can override any other rules by setting the !important attribute:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none !important; 
}
```